# Partial derivatives of $\ln(x+y)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble with because in my guide the answer is different.

I want to calculate the total derivative of the function: $f(x,y)=\ln(x+y)$

By definition: The Total derivative/Chain rule for functions of functions.

If $\omega=f(x,y)$ a continuous function. Then the **total derivative** is:

$$\frac{\partial \omega }{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \omega }{\partial x}\frac{d x }{d t} +  \frac{\partial \omega }{\partial y}\frac{d y }{d t}  $$

For our case $t=x+y$ and $$\omega= f(x,y)=\ln(x+y)$$ I got:

$$\frac{1}{x+y}$$

But in the book, the correct answer is:

$$\frac{x+y}{x+y}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the correct answer is $\frac 1 {x+y}$. You do not know that the derivatives of $x$ and $y$ w.r.t. are $1$ each but the derivative of their sum is $1$.

Comment: Hi Kavy, for me it's the same. I modified the answer...

Comment: The function is $\log(t)$ and obviously its derivative on $t$ is $\dfrac1t$.

Comment: @LorenzoCastagno Your answer is correct. The book has  a wrong answer.

Comment: @Thanks, I wanted to confirm with someone else. Thanks

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy I think it was typo.

Comment: Are you sure the book's answer doesn't say $\frac{\dot x + \dot y}{x+y}$, with the dots denoting time derivatives ($\dot x = dx/dt$, $\dot y = dy/dt$)?

Comment: You say "For our case  $=+$".  How do you get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book definitely got that wrong. Since $\omega=\ln t$, $\partial_t\omega=\frac{1}{t}$. The chain rule agrees:$$\partial_x\omega=\partial_y\omega=\partial_t\omega=\frac{1}{t}\implies\partial_t\omega=\frac{1}{t}\frac{d}{dt}(x+y)=\frac{1}{t}.$$

Comment: I don't think $x+y=t$ is the correct interpretation. From the given formula for the total derivative, it seems that $x$ and $y$ should be considered as functions of $t$, so it's $\omega(t) = \ln(x(t)+y(t))$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Normally, yes, but the OP said $t=x+y$.

Comment: Yes, he did, but without any explanation, and probably incorrectly (if I may guess).

Comment: @HansLundmark An alarmingly good point. Reply to this comment if we ever learn a specific alternative relation between $t,\,x,\,y$, in which case I shall update my answer.